# CoroutineLiveData Builder repository not being invoked

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, coroutine, mutablelivedata

I'm trying to use the new liveData builder referenced [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) to retrieve my data, then transform it into view models. However, my repository code isn't being invoked (at least I'm not able to see it being triggered when I use my debugger). Am I not supposed to use two `liveData{ ... }` builders? (one in my repository, one in my view model)?

```
class MyRepository @Inject constructor() : Repository {

    override fun getMyContentLiveData(params: MyParams): LiveData<MyContent> =
    liveData {

        val myContent = networkRequest(params) // send network request with params
        emit(myContent)
    }
}


class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: MyRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val viewModelList = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val contentLiveData = repository.getContentLiveData(keyParams)
        val viewModelLiveData = contentToViewModels(contentLiveData)
        emit(viewModelLiveData)
}

    private fun contentToViewModels(contentLiveData: LiveData<MyContent>): LiveData<List<ViewModel>> {
        return Transformations.map(contentLiveData) { content ->
            //perform some transformation and return List<ViewModel>
        }
    }
}

class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    val myViewModel: MyViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    }

    lateinit var params: MyParams

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
        super.onAttach(context)
        myViewModel.params = params
        myViewModel.viewModelList.observe(this, Observer {
            onListChanged(it) 
        })

    }
```

Comment: You seem to be setting up a `LiveData` to emit another `LiveData`. That seems odd. Should that be `val viewModelList = contentToViewModels(repository.getContentLiveData(keyParams))`?

Comment: I'll give that a try.

Comment: @CommonsWare That didn't work. The repository is still being skipped entirely.

Comment: You also might want to take a look at the `emitSource` thingie - it seems like it's made for you :) https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with the `emitSource`:

```
val viewModelList = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    emitSource(
        repository.getContentLiveData(keyParams).map {
            contentToViewModels(it)
        }
}
```

Comment: Yep this was the missing piece. Thanks!